# ebxm client for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workflow, webdav, ebxml

Is there an ebxml implementation for ruby? I've seen [hefeweizen](http://rubyforge.org/projects/hefeweizen/), but I think that this project died years ago. I have a project that needs support for workflow, ebxml and webdav. I prefer ruby on rails over java with jaxr and jbpm.